# PHP Question Array Select using

Tags: php

I have a php array....

```
<?php $state = array("Kentucky", "Ohio", "West Virginia", "Indiana", "Texas");
```

How would I get this aray to report to this select list.

```
<select size="1" name="state" id="state">
 <option>Select One</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use `foreach` and `echo`. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select size="1" name="state" id="state">
<?php
foreach($state as $state_name)
{
   echo '<option value="' . $state_name . '">' . $state_name . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: you wouldn't need the value attribute if it is just the same as the text

Comment: I knew it was a foreach loop but I was not so sure how to use it.  So when you use a for each loop you have to name it something else?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, you define the array you're going to iterate through and the variable that will store the current iteration value. [Read more about foreach](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$state = array("Kentucky", "Ohio", "West Virginia", "Indiana", "Texas");
?>

<select size="1" name="state" id="state">
<option>Select One</option>
<?php 
   foreach($state AS $val){
       echo "<option>$val</option>";
   }
 ?>
</select>
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can implode (expand the array)

```
<select size="1" name="state" id="state">
<option>Select One</option>
<option>
<?php
  $state = array("Kentucky", "Ohio", "West Virginia", "Indiana", "Texas");
  echo implode('</option><option>', state);
?>
</option>
</select>
```